# Maximum value that satisfies a specific function

Tags: python, performance

I want to find the maximum value for a that doesn't change the output from another function. (_find_mean simply finds the location of the maximum element in a matrix)

This is how I am currently doing it and was wondering if there was a better way.

```
def _find_max_a(matrix1, matrix2):
    a = np.arange(0,10, 0.01)[::-1]
    for val in a:
        mat = matrix1 +  val * matrix2
        if _find_mean(matrix1) == _find_mean(mat):
            return val
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Doesn't this code return for any value within `a` which doesn't change the output from the other function?

Comment: And your loop doesn't change `a`, it loops on values of `a`. So is your description correct?

Answer (score 8):

- `arange` can build a descending vector. Building an ascending vector and reversing it seems wasteful. Consider

  ```
  a = np.arange(10, 0, -0.01)
  ```
- `matrix1` is never modified, but its `_find_mean` is recomputed on each iteration. Yet another waste. Compute it once.
- Instead of linear search, you may want to consider a bisection of the search interval.
- `else: pass` achieves nothing, and can be safely omitted.
- `_find_mean` is a kinda strange name for a function which

  > finds the location of the maximum element in a matrix

Comment: Now the question is how to do the `arange` thing more efficiently. For larger range with finer accuracy, the amount of required memory is quite high (800kB for range `100, 0, -0.001` with `dtype` of `np.float64`, which is the default). Loop with manual decrement by `0.001` would introduce errors, whereas a scaled loop would require division.